# Python Regex for Searching pattern in text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, list

Tags in Sample.txt:

`<ServiceRQ>want everything between...</ServiceRQ>`

`<ServiceRQ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance>want everything between</ServiceRQ>`
..

Please can someone help me to get the regex? To extract the expected output from a text file. I want to create a regex to find the above tags.
This is what is have tried `re.search(r"<(.*?)RQ(.*?)>(.*?)</(.*?)RQ>", line)` but not working properly. I want to make a search based on word RQ in text file

The expected output should be

```
1. <ServiceRQ>want everything between</ServiceRQ>
2. <ServiceRQ> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance>want everything between</ServiceRQ>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern

```
regex= r'<\w+RQ.*?>.*?</\w+RQ>'
data=re.findall(regex, line)
```

The above regex will give output like

```
['<ServiceRQ>want everything between...</ServiceRQ>', '<ServiceRQ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance>want everything between</ServiceRQ>']
```

Answer (score 0):

As Ashish has mentioned, this one gives the tag including the contents.

```
regex= r'<\w+RQ.*?>.*?</\w+RQ>'
data=re.findall(regex, line)
```

You can also do this to retrieve JUST the contents within the tags. Changing `.*?` to `(.*?)` between the tags.

```
regex = r'<\w+RQ.*?>(.*?)<\/\w+RQ>'
data = re.findall(regex, sample)
```

This would result in the following output:

```
['want everything between...', 'want everything between']
```